# Which command to use to execute a program within C++ code [Linux]?

Tags: c++, linux, command, ipc

Greetings,

Am new to C++ and Linux. Am looking for a command that I use to execute 3 executable programs (exe/bin) in my source code, and this what i want to do:
1. Know if the process executed successfully (return value)
2. Know process ID
3. Kill a process

I tried System(), but it doesn't return on error and no PID, also not safe. I had a quick look at fork()-exec() but is it possible not to have parent-child relation? Also, i looked into the man pages but i didn't understand :(

Please, advice me on which command I shall use.

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 3):

Have you looked at popen()?  This might be the way to go.
Try the man page.

Answer (score 2):

[system()](http://linux.die.net/man/3/system) does return the exit code of the child process the same way [wait()](http://linux.die.net/man/2/wait) does (or `-1` on error, or `127` if it failed to spawn the shell process).

If you need to know the PID of the child and run it asynchronously, [fork()](http://linux.die.net/man/3/fork) followed by [exec()](http://linux.die.net/man/3/exec) is usually the way to go. Use [popen()](http://linux.die.net/man/3/popen) instead if you want to communicate with the child process through a pipe.

To alleviate the inherent parent/child relationship, you'll probably have to [daemonize](http://www-theorie.physik.unizh.ch/~dpotter/howto/daemonize) the child process.

Answer (score 1):

By definition, you *always* have a parent-child relation when starting new programs (except when they replace your own program in the current process; you get that when calling `execl` without `fork`ing first). Functions likes `system` and `popen` internally also call `fork` and one of the `exec` variants.

Have a look at [Fork and Exec tutorial](http://www.eng.cam.ac.uk/help/tpl/unix/fork.html) from the University of Cambridge, it's pretty straight-forward and to the point. Also uses C++. Note that all the relevant calls (`fork`, `execl`, `wait`) are C POSIX functions.